# How to use Blanket.js with QUnit tests run with jQuery.noConflict(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, code-coverage, blanket.js

I am using `QUnit` to test the `jQuery plugin` I'm writing and was hoping to use `blanket` to generate coverage information.

My test looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Awesome Test Suite</title>
  <!-- Load local jQuery. This can be overridden with a ?jquery=___ param. -->
  <script src="../libs/jquery-loader.js"></script>

  <!-- Load local QUnit. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/qunit/qunit.css" media="screen">
  <script src="../libs/qunit/qunit.js"></script>

  <!-- Code Coverage with Blanket -->
  <script src="../node_modules/blanket/dist/qunit/blanket.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Load local lib and tests. -->
  <script src="../build/thingToTest.js" data-cover></script>
  <script src="../build/test/thingToTest_test.js"></script>
  <!-- Removing access to jQuery and $. But it'll still be available as _$, if
       you REALLY want to mess around with jQuery in the console. REMEMBER WE
       ARE TESTING A PLUGIN HERE, THIS HELPS ENSURE BEST PRACTICES. REALLY. -->
  <script>window._$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit">
    <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Tests</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
  </div>
  <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
  <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <div class="thingToTest-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this in a browser I see the `enable coverage` option but when I check that option I get the error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.fn')
Source: file:///Users/dave/src/thingToTest/test/thingToTest.html?coverage=true:317
```

If I comment out the line

```
<script>window._$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

then `blanket` works just fine.

In simple cases this is acceptable, but in more complex cases I'd really want to load jQuery in `noConflict` mode to ensure test purity.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I added data-cover to the jQuery script tag in the HTML for qUnit tests and it worked, I think the instrument needs to see it.

**EDIT**

I also noticed this line in my html for qUnit.

```
<!-- Removing access to jQuery and $. But it'll still be available as _$, if
  you REALLY want to mess around with jQuery in the console. REMEMBER WE
  ARE TESTING A PLUGIN HERE, THIS HELPS ENSURE BEST PRACTICES. REALLY. -->
<script>window._$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

By removing that block it no longer needed the data-cover on the jQuery tag.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering which is better, adding coverage to the whole of jQuery (not likely to give sensible coverage stats) or not running jQuery in `noConflict` mode.  I suspect the latter, but am looking for a solution that allows me to take advantage of using `noConflict`.